# Mercurial repository - Output in chinese

Tags: mercurial, repository

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, I just have installed Mercurial.

I've created a new repository and, when I, for example, show the log, the output It's in chinese.

How I can change this?

Example:

```
修改集:      1:b2f2b495c5a0
标签:        tip
用户:        yo
日期:        Sun Jan 13 16:33:28 2013 +0100
摘要:        actualización de ficheros
```

My locale

```
yo@yo:~/Projects/wik$ locale
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_ES:es_HN:es_CR:es_CO:es_CL:es_AR:zh_CN:en
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I've tired with

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

but didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please at least attempt to find the answer yourself first.  First result on google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592664/hg-how-do-i-change-the-language-of-my-mercurialhg-installation-macos. There are plenty more resources after that one.

Comment: I have tried that at first but didn't work. In fact, the output was like "??: 1:b2f2b495c5a0; ??: tip..." and I'm using Ubuntu, not MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
LANGUAGE=es_ES:es_HN:es_CR:es_CO:es_CL:es_AR:zh_CN:en
                                             ^^^^^
```

In your session is a Chinese language embedded. Check your localisation settings why it is there.

You can disable this in a shell when you enter

```
LANGUAGE=es_ES:es_HN:es_CR:es_CO:es_CL:es_AR:en
export LANGUAGE
```

You can also put this in your .bashrc so it get executed every time you run an interactive shell.