# How to permanently change the language of mercurial command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, mercurial

How can I change the language of the mercurial command line permanently to english on Windows? Setting the LANG environment variable as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650477/285288) helps temporarily for one command window, but can the language be set somehow in mercurial.ini (or hgrc) or somehow else?

The reason behind this: the German output of mercurial is broken in a way that all special characters (Umlaute etc.) are not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `LANGUAGE` environment variable to `en_US.UTF-8` either for current user or globally using `Control Panel` -> `All Control Panel Items` -> `System` -> `Advanced system settings` -> `Advanced` -> `Environment variables`, create new variable in `User` or `System`.

After creating it, your changes will only apply for new instances of `cmd` or other programs.

Note, that it seems that `LANGUAGE` env. variable is not something that most other programs pay any attention to, except for `hg` or `TortoiseHg`. I was able to install it in my Windows 7 box (English) and set `LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8`. This has changed `hg` to report most messages in German, but it did not affect any other of my programs - they still speak English.

Comment: Like commented on the other answer: I do not want to set the LANG environment variable "globally". I only would like to change the language of mercurial.

Comment: I have updated my answer to mention that using `LANGUAGE` does not seem to affect other programs.

Comment: Thanks. Although this also seems to be a bit of a "hack" it seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to change your command line language to english, go to your mercurial installation path (e.g. on windows `C:\Program Files\Mercurial\`) then `/locale/` and rename the wrong current language folder (e.g. de) to _de.

Now hg will fall back to the default language en

Comment: This works like a charm and is why I generally choose not to install language files in the first place, also for programs other than Mercurial if their installer allows to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you used [`SET`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to set the environment variable. This will only modify the variable for the lifetime of the current command window.

Have you tried setting the LANG environment variable permanently using [`SETX`](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)? This will modify the variable permanently. However, please note that it will not modify the current command window, so you will need to open a new command window to see the effect of the change.

Comment: I do not want to set the LANG environment variable "globally". I only would like to change the language of mercurial.