# how can I force the hg executable to use English local for its output?

Tags: mercurial, locale

Mercurial's output may be localized. This is nasty when parsing command output and it actually may break such code. Is there some command line option or environment variable which can be used to force Mercurial to use *English* locale?

Comment: More or less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592664, however the common term "locale" wasn't used there at all, hence it didn't show up when asking this question and for my initial search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a linux shell (Bash, bsh, sh), use:

```
LANG=en_US hg <status/log/etc>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing script that interact with the mercurial executable then you probably want to look at the [Command Server](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommandServer), or if you're writing python scripts [hgapi](https://bitbucket.org/haard/hgapi).

These will give you interfaces which don't have localised strings in them.